# When using Delegatecall or callcode, which Ether balance is used?

Tags: ether, delegatecall, callcode

Simple question, but I couldn’t find the answer.

When contract A CALLCODE B, B will uses A’s ledger. But which Ether balance will be used if B makes a normal transfer, the balance of A or the balance of B ?

Answer (score -1):

I think its always the balance from address reduced whosoever initiate the transaction/transfer. In this case balance of B.
and yes B need some balance beforehand to do so.

Comment: Do you think, or do you have proofs ? Given that calling codesize from B gives the codesize of A (see instructions.Go in go Ethereum) I doubt so. Also if it was true, this would allows tricking B that A owns B for sending funds. Using B balance makes sense but sounds unlikely. So I don’t know. **Please leave the question marked as unanswered if you won’t edit your answer through deleting your answer**